# cs50x problem set 5 - Is this how to properly load a linked list into a hashtable?

Tags: c, cs50

Specifically where it says:

```
table[i] = n;
```

Is it loading the correct linked list into the correct bucket?

I'm not getting any errors at the moment but I have a feeling that it isn't correct and will hinder my progress when I move on to the next functions. I just want to make sure that my function puts the linked lists in the correct bucket in regards to the index.

```
bool load(const char \*dictionary)
{
char word\[LENGTH + 1\];

    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open\n");
        return false;
    }
    
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    
        if(n != NULL){
            strcpy(n->word, word);
        } else{
            printf("Unable to open\n");
            return false;
        }
    
        unsigned int i = hash(word);
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    
        table[i] = n;
    
        //Inserts new word onto the link lists
        new_node->next = table[i];
        table[i] = new_node;
    
    
    }
    
    fclose(file);
    
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Do not tag `C++` for `C` code.  The code is obviously `C`, since this `node *n = malloc(sizeof(node))` will not compile for C++ if `node *` is not a void pointer.

Comment: Side note: you don't want to escape your code. You might want to escape characters in a string literal in your code, but the code itself should be posted unchanged.

Comment: Side note: EOF is one of MANY possible return values from `fscanf` that you need to examine carefully before trusting what was read. By only checking EOF, you're leaving a lot to chance and will pay for it in extra debugging.